# Edit Value of a Key in a LinkedHashMap inside an ArrayList that’s inside another LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, arraylist, linkedhashmap

Let's say I have the following data structure like this:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<LinkedHashMap>> foodFamilies = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

that looks something like this:

```
{Fruit = [{Name = Apple, 
           Color = }, 
          {Name = Cherry, 
           Color = }], 
 Vegetables = [{Name = Beet,
                Color = }]}
```

How can I elegantly insert the color “red” for every color of every food in each family?

Comment: Refactor to use a `Food` class, then use a stream or Groovy closure iterator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
for (List<LinkedHashMap> list : foodFamilies.values())
    for (LinkedHashMap map : list)
        map.put("Color", "red");
```

By the way, you should not use the raw type `LinkedHashMap`. It should be a `LinkedHashMap<String, String>` (I think).

I also think that you should be using a class with two fields `name` and `color` rather than a `Map` anyway.